# Cannot find symbol error sorting Collection with Collections.sort()

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

***Edit: Solved! Thanks everybody.***

I'm trying to sort a collection in Java using the Comparator with no luck. Here's my code:

```
public class Collections_Exercise {

    public void runExercise(){

        String[] emailArray =  {"andy@test.com","paul@test.com","cindy@test.com", "robert@test.com", "bill@test.com", "andy@test.com", "cindy@test.com"};

        Collection<String>emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));    
        processEmails(emails);

        // 5.  Call processEmails with a sorted list of emails with duplicate email addresses removed
        System.out.println("Sorted list of emails with no dups!");

        class alphabeticalComparator implements Comparator<String> 
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(String email1, String email2)
            {
                int result = email1.toString().compareTo(email2.toString());
                return result;
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(emails, new alphabeticalComparator()); //Doesn't work, can't find collections.sort() symbol
        processEmails(emails);

        private void processEmails(Collection<String> emails)
        {
                for( String s : emails)
                        System.out.println(s);
        }



        public static void main(String [] args)
        {
                new Collections_Exercise().runExercise();
        }
}
```

No matter what I try I can't get Collections.sort() to work. Any tips?

Edit: This is the error that terminal is giving me:

```
Collections_Exercise.java:58: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method sort(java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>,alphabeticalComparator)
location: class java.util.Collections
Collections.sort(emails, new alphabeticalComparator());
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you mean when you say "I can't get Collections.sort()"  what is the exact issue

Comment: Have you tried moving your comparator class outside of the method?

Comment: The natrual sort of Strings is alphabetical.  Call Collections.sort() without passing in a comparator and see if that works.

Comment: @JustinKSU still giving the same error :( Can't find Collections.sort().

Comment: Just a pointer, email1 and email2 inside the comparator are of type String, there is no need to toString() them again while comparing

Comment: When you solve a question, post your answer for others to see. Then, unless someone else beat you to it, accept the answer as correct. That way, others who visit the site will see how it was solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) takes a `List`, not a `Collection`.

```
List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));
```

The reason for this is that there are some classes implementing Collection that cannot be reordered arbitrarily. Some have a storage mechanism that depends on elements being placed strategically (such as HashSet) and others have a predetermined sorted order (such as TreeSet).

[Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) says this about it:

> The root interface in the collection hierarchy. ... Some are ordered and others unordered. The JDK [only] provides implementations of more specific subinterfaces like Set and List. This interface is typically used ... where maximum generality is desired.

Hence why you only see Collection as a parameter in places like conversion constructors (which [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) calls a convention) and the family of [xxxAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll%28java.util.Collection%29) methods.

Comment: you are right, but another problem is that he missed a } as I wrote, there were 2 problems ;)

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks much. Upvoted and will accept answer in ~4 minutes when I can.

Comment: @Alessio It's true but that might just be a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 2):

In Java a container of type `Collection`, by definition, has no order and can therefore not be sorted. Only its child `List` can be ordered.

Consequently the [Collections#sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method expects an object of type `List` as first argument, but you are providing a Collection.

Change

```
Collection<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));
```

into

```
List<String> emails = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss a

```
}
```

after  processEmails(emails);

and you have to change from

```
Collection<String>
```

to

```
List<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

Original

```
Collection<String>emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));
```

New

```
ListString>emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));
```

As per Java API Collections.sort accept List.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> emails = Arrays.asList(emailArray);
Collections.sort(emails, new alphabeticalComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort()` expects a `List` not a `Collection`, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Thus, instead of

```
Collection<String>emails = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(emailArray));
```

it should be

```
final List<String>emails = Arrays.asList(emailArray);
```